# VS 2008 - Publish Web Site - Exclude App_Data

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment

How do I prevent Visual Studio 2008 (standard edition) from publishing the App_Data folder?  I can't have the contents of App_Data published because it ruthlessly overwrites the production data.

Answer (score 0):

The publish dialog has a checkbox option at the bottom to "Include files from the App_Data folder".

Comment: I am not seeing this checkbox.  I have VS 2008 standard edition.

Comment: That's weird. Maybe your project is a web site and it only works with web applications?

Comment: Yes it is a web site.  Is that a problem?